# Pandas - Ignoring empty values when concatenating grouped rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to group a dataframe based on a column value, and I want to concatenate (join) the values in the other columns.

I'm doing something like -

```
df_combined = df_combined.groupby('UC').agg({'LO Number': ', '.join,
                                             'K Code': ', '.join})
```

But, this gives me some `nan` values where the `K Code` columns has no values. So the result looks like

```
K Code

K0016, K0068, nan, nan, A0046

nan, nan, nan
```

How can I get rid of these nan values in the `K Code` column? Also, is there a way to get a third column that has the number of values present in `K Code` column. For eg. for the above,

```
Count

3   

0
```

Edit: Sample Data -

```
UC      LO Number      K Code
C001     C001.1        K0068
C001     C001.2        K0372
C002     C002.1        
C002     C002.3        K0032
C002     C002.5
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Would you like show us your sample data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `lambda` with `agg`, however this will create the multiple index

Since you nan is `nan` do replace before run below

```
df=df.replace({'nan':np.nan})


df_combined.groupby('UC').agg({'LO Number': ', '.join,
                                             'K Code': [lambda x : ', '.join(y for y in x if y==y),'count']})
```

If you do not want the multiple index

```
df_combined.assign(count=df_combined['K Code']).
         groupby('UC').agg({'LO Number': ', '.join,
                           'K Code': lambda x : ', '.join(y for y in x if y==y),
                            'count':'count'})
```

Comment: @harry04 make sure your nan is np.nan not “nan” which is string

Comment: I think it's "nan" and not np.nan (which is displayed as NaN if I'm not wrong).

Comment: @harry04 adding this before my code df = df. replace({‘nan’:np.nan})